# Python: prevent values in Pandas Series rounding to integer

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

I was trying to set some values on a Series, but it will automatically round to an integer, what should I do to prevent this?

```
from __future__ import division
import pandas as pd

In [100]: series = pd.Series(range(20))

In [101]: series[10]
Out[101]: 10

In [102]: series[10] = 0.05

In [103]: series[10]
Out[103]: 0

In [104]: series[10] = 2.5

In [105]: series[10]
Out[105]: 2

In [106]: series[10] = float(2.5)

In [107]: series[10]
Out[107]: 2

In [108]: float(2/3)
Out[108]: 0.6666666666666666

In [109]: series[10] = float(2/3)

In [110]: series[10]
Out[110]: 0
```

Comment: [pandas.Series documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) - as an answer already mentioned, it looks like you'll want to use `dtype=(type)`.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I should go through the documentation before asking.

Comment: Because you instantiated a Series of int. Instead of float. It's doing exactly what your code is asking it to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`series` is automatically created with the `int64` data type (since `range(20)` contains only integers). When you try to set a value of this Series to a float, the values is truncated to an integer because Pandas won't automatically promote the data type of the Series.*

The easiest way around this is to create you Series with the required datatype:

```
series = pd.Series(range(20), dtype=float)
```

Or you could cast the integer Series once it has been created:

```
series = series.astype(float)
```

You will then be able to set float values to the Series.

---

* This is somewhat similar to NumPy's behaviour with arrays. However, unlike NumPy, Pandas *will* promote the data type of a Series from integer to floating type if you try to set a `nan` value:

```
series[10] = np.nan # series is promoted to float64 type
```

Pandas will also promote the Series to an `object` datatype if you try set a string value:

```
series[5] = 'some string' # series is promoted to object type
```